# Как отрегулировать количество эпох для нейронной сети? По умолчанию используется 250

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

```
!python --version

!wget -O mini.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x mini.sh
!bash ./mini.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y jupyter
!conda install -q -y google-colab -c conda-forge
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py39" --user
!curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | bash
!apt-get install git-lfs
!git clone https://github.com/marcoppasini/musika.git
%cd musika
!pip install -r requirements.txt
!mkdir core # you can upload mp3's to this folder
!python musika_encode.py --files_path core --save_path prepared_for_training
!python musika_train.py --train_path prepared_for_training --load_path /content/musika/checkpoints/misc --lr 0.00004

!python musika_generate.py --load_path checkpoints/misc --num_samples 1 --seconds 30 --save_path generations

from IPython.display import Audio
Audio('/content/musika/generations/0_20221214-105909.wav')
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно разобрался в скриптах, то нужно просто добавить параметр `epochs` с нужным значением при вызове `train`:

```
!python musika_train.py --epochs 100 --train_path prepared_for_training --load_path /content/musika/checkpoints/misc --lr 0.00004
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```